# Redirecting user request, nodeJS

Tags: node.js, email, redirect, webserver

I'm building a little email server based on nodeJS (homework). When a user tries to login I check that he has an account and then redirect him to `/user/userName`.
I set the response status to `201 Created`, and then added a header `Location: /user/userName`

I checked in chrome's developer tools that the response was what I sent and it was, yet the location does not change. Any ideas why, or how to do it better?

Thanks

Comment: are you using any framework or just plain node?

Comment: plain ndoe, can't use anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP response code for a permanent redirect is `301`, not `201`. Your browser will not use the `location` header to redirect you with a `201`. Before you change to `301`, though, make sure you don't want a temporary redirect, or `302`, instead!

Comment: what's the difference between 301 and 302 in practice? thanks!

Comment: 301s are cached by many (most?) clients. Effectively, you're telling the client, "Never come back to address A, use address B instead." 302s are temporary, "We've finished with logic at address A, move along to address B."